# How do I retain the decimal numbers during text preprocessing in python?(Edited)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def text_process(text):  
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    return " ".join(text)
```

Input text: 'Transaction value was - RS.3456.63 '

Output : 'Transaction value was  RS 345663 '

Could someone suggest me how to remove special characters (including '.' ) during text pre-processing but retain the decimal numbers?

Required Output : 'Transaction value was  RS 3456.63 '

Comment: First, define exactly what you mean by number. Does `a334.65b` count? Does `45.` count? How about `86.fgh`?

Comment: In your example, what output would you like?

Comment: Just the decimal numbers, not any alphanumeric terms like 'a334.65b' .Should only be able to retain '3456.63' from 'rs.3456.63'.

Comment: That was just an example but not working well if its preceding or succeeding with '.' and a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this code is for you:

```
text = 'Transaction value was, - 3456.63 Rupees'

regex = r"(?<!\d)[" + string.punctuation + "](?!\d)"
result = re.sub(regex, "", text)
# output: 'Transaction value was  3456.63 Rupees'
```

To solve your second question, try using this trick:

```
text = 'Transaction value was, - Rs.3456.63'

regex_space = r"([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)"
regex_punct = r'[^\w.]+'

re.sub(r'[^\w.]+', ' ', re.sub(regex_space,r" \1 ", text).strip())
# output: 'Transaction value was Rs. 3456.63 Rupees'
```

Comment: text = 'Transaction value was, - Rs.3456.63'

regex = r"(?<!\d)[''+-.,;:""_@](?!\d)"
result = re.sub(regex, "", text)

Problem is , 

output : 'Transaction value was  Rs.3456.63' has '.' between 'Rs' and the number.


How to preprocess this and retain decimal?

Comment: Try this trick: re.sub(regex, ' ', re.sub(r"([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)",r" \1 ", text).strip())

Answer (score 3):

You can use a more generic regex to replace all special characters except .

```
import re
def text_process(text):  
    text = re.sub('[^\w.]+', ' ', text)
    return text

s = 'Transaction: value* #was - 3456.63 Rupees'
text_process(s)
```

You get

```
'Transaction value was 3456.63 Rupees'
```

EDIT: The following function returns only the number with decimals.

```
def text_process(text):  
    text = re.sub('[^\d.]+', '', text)
    return text

s = 'Transaction: value* #was - 3456.63 Rupees'
text_process(s)

'3456.63'
```

Comment: But,its not working on  'Transaction: value* #was - Rs.3456.63 ' .I still have 'Rs.3456.63' in my output.

Comment: Isn't your problem statement - "remove special characters (including '.' ) during text pre-processing but retain the decimal numbers?" ? What would be the expected output for the above string?

Comment: After using the above code, im left with '.3456.63' for the above mentioned text(edited).Could you please check again.